# Finding an approximation for $\sin^2\theta$ where $\theta=\theta_m+\delta t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let $\theta_m$ be a constant and $0<\delta\ll1$. Let $\theta=\theta_m+\delta t$ then my lecturer states

$$\sin^2\theta = \sin^2\theta_m + O(\delta^2)$$

however I'm struggling to see how this has been obtained. Could someone break it down for me?

Comment: Use Taylor for $\sin(\theta)$ around $\theta_m$ and square it.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That doesn't work. The taylor series is $$\sin(\theta_m+\delta t) = \sin\theta_m + \delta t\cos{\theta_m} + O(\delta^2)$$ then squaring this gives $$\sin^2(\theta_m+\delta t) = \sin^2\theta_m + 2\delta t\cos\theta_m\sin\theta_m + O(\delta^2)=\sin^2\theta_m + O(\delta)$$ but we want $+O(\delta^2)$..

Answer (score 2):

We will use $\sin{\delta t}=\delta t+O(\delta t)$ and $\cos{\delta t}=1+O(\delta t)$ and the key is

$$\sin(\theta_m+\delta t)=\sin{\theta_m}\cos{\delta t}+\cos{\theta_m}\sin{\delta t}=\sin{\theta_m}+\delta t\cos{\theta_m}+O(\delta t)$$

Squaring and keeping the first order we get the expected result

Comment: Hmm but expanding we still don't get the correct result - Firstly shouldn't we have $\sin{\delta t}=\delta t+O(\delta^2t^2)$ and $\cos{\delta t}=1+O(\delta^2t^2)$? Expanding we then get $$\sin(\theta_m+\delta t) = \sin\theta_m+\delta t\cos{\theta_m}+O(\delta^2t^2)$$ then squaring this we get $$\sin^2(\theta_m+\delta t)=\sin^2\theta_m + 2\delta t\sin\theta_m\cos\theta_m+O(\delta^2t^2)=\sin^2\theta_m+O(\delta)$$ rather than $O(\delta^2)$ which is what we need

Comment: It is just because it is $O(\delta)$